# include ROS into external CMake project (OpentTLD)

Tags: ros, external-libraries, build, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to extend the OpenTLD project to use it with ros. I'm using the C++ port from Georg Nebehay ( https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD ).
This project is build with cmake and multiple custom CmakeLists.txt files.

Unfortunately I am not sure how I have to change my own packages CMakeLists.txt to build OpenTLD with the need cmake settings?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40433/include-ros-into-external-cmake-project-(openttld)/) by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-09-25**:
Did you ever get this working?

**Comment by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) on 2012-10-08**:
Yes, but i only have it running with a hardcoded boundary box. If you want i will upload it to github so you can use and modify it.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-12-31**:
yes, if you could post it on github I would like that ... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your answer.
In the end i followed another way.
I adapted the CMakeLists.txt to reflect to custom CMakeLists.txt files from the OpenTLD package.

Before I didn't know you could do it this way. This site helped me a lot.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists

---

Originally posted by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) with karma: 206 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote this file to achieve this goal:
[ros.cmake](https://github.com/jrl-umi3218/jrl-cmakemodules/blob/master/ros.cmake)

It is self-contained.
Example:

```
ADD_ROSPACK_DEPENDENCY(urdf) # check for urdf presence and detect flags.
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib ...) # define some target here... mylib for instance.
ROSPACK_USE_DEPENDENCY(mylib urdf) # link mylib against urdf.
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davheld](https://answers.ros.org/users/1371/davheld/) on 2013-02-24**:
This is great, thanks!

**Comment by [davheld](https://answers.ros.org/users/1371/davheld/) on 2013-03-09**:
Actually it seems that this no longer works with groovy (works great with all released up through fuerte though!)

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-03-10**:
This macro has been designed to detect packages through rospack. I.e. packages built with rosbuild. When packages are using catkin, this is their own responsibility to install files which can be used for compilation flags detection. I.e. a .pc (pkg-config) file or a rosmacro.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-03-10**:
With what package(s) is it failing?